# react-hook-form with Material UI RadioGroup selected value is always NULL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

Trying to use RadioGroup from Material UI wrapped with react-hook-form Controller, always getting the selected value null, here is my code, I wonder what I am missing?

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel,
  FormHelperText,
  Radio,
  RadioGroup
} from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useFormContext, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

interface IOptionTypes {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  value: string;
  desc?: string;
}

interface IFormElementTypes {
  name: string;
  options: IOptionTypes[];
}

export default function RadioFieldElement({
  name,
  options
}: IFormElementTypes) {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      defaultValue=""
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <RadioGroup
            {...field}
            {...register(name)}
            row
            onChange={(event, value) => field.onChange(value)}
            value={field.value}
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={option.id}
                value={option.value}
                control={<Radio />}
                label={option.label}
              />
            ))}
          </RadioGroup>
          <FormHelperText>{String(errors[name]?.message ?? "")}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Here is the live code.

[image: Edit calc (forked)]

Just simply select any value from list and press submit in console you will see the value is null always.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `RadioFieldElement.tsx` you don't need to put `{...register(name)}` on your `RadioGroup`. Simply remove that and everything will work as expected:

```
<RadioGroup
  {...field}
  // remove this line ---> {...register(name)}
  row
  onChange={(event, value) => field.onChange(value)}
  value={field.value}
>
```

Here's a full codesandbox example: [image: Edit calc (forked)]

Comment: This works!! Thanks a lot, would you help me understand why don't we need to register here?

Comment: Based on [the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) I believe it's because the Controller component takes care of the registration process. To use `register` you need to have access to that component's ref

Answer (score 1):

> RadioFieldElement.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel,
  FormHelperText,
  Radio,
  RadioGroup
} from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form"; // use useForm

interface IOptionTypes {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  value: string;
  desc?: string;
}

interface IFormElementTypes {
  name: string;
  options: IOptionTypes[];
}

export default function RadioFieldElement({
  name,
  options
}: IFormElementTypes) {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  /* const [theValue, setTheValue] = useState(control._defaultValues[name]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);

    setTheValue(event.target.value);
  }; */

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      defaultValue=""
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <RadioGroup
            {...field}
            {...register(name)}
            row
            onChange={(event, value) => field.onChange(value)}
            value={field.value}
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={option.id}
                value={option.value}
                control={<Radio />}
                label={option.label}
              />
            ))}
          </RadioGroup>
          <FormHelperText>{String(errors[name]?.message ?? "")}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `mui-react-form-plus` as it is already tested and ready to use for production.

```
import { HookRadioButton, useHookForm } from 'mui-react-hook-form-plus'
```

```
const { registerState } = useHookForm({
    defaultValues: {
        breverage: 'wine',
        isAdmin: true,
    },
});

<HookRadioButton
    {...registerState('breverage')}
    label='Breverage'
    fields={[
        { label: 'Coke', value: 'coke' },
        { label: 'Wine', value: 'wine' },
    ]}
/>
```

[Form more look into:](https://mui-react-hook-form-plus.vercel.app/?path=/docs/hookradiobutton--hookradiobutton)

https://mui-react-hook-form-plus.vercel.app/?path=/docs/hookradiobutton--hookradiobutton